# Are nested python try-except blocks bad code or code smell?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a situation where, I get an object, fillable_object which I need to fill out and I have another object, filler_object, that I use to fill up the first object. The filler_object however, can be of different types that don't have the same attributes. In which case I want the fields related to that in the fillable_object to get the value null.

What I thought of was to group for each class that fillable_object can be, in a try except block. Since the attribute sets of the different classes are mutually exclusive it will either get all of them or non, then try for the next type etc. Currently there aren't too many classes that fillable_object can have, but I can see it as being annoying to maintain later if the number increases.

```
def fill_with(fillable, filler):
    try:
        fillable.attr1 = filler.attr1
    except AttrError:
        try:
            fillable.attr2 = filler.attr2
            fillable.attr3 = filler.attr3
        except AttrError:
            try:
                #Continue for each class filler can be.
            except AttrError:
return fillable
```

Comment: To avoid nesting you can place a return at the end of each try block and a "pass" in the except. So the try blocks can be placed one after another.

Comment: Yea but if I do that it would be redundant. If the filler object is of one type it can't be of any of the others so I would do x assignments redundant and throw class_count of  exceptions. It might not be much of a resource waste but still

Comment: looks like XY problem...

Comment: @hkBst Could you please elaborate?

Comment: To test if a particular attribute is present, there is `hasattr()`. To test for the type/class of an object there are `type()` and `isinstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is definitely a code smell, and you found why: what happens when you add new `filler` objects? You have to rewrite your function. This is a violation of the [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

> software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification

Concretely, you can use some workarounds, but you are in a typical "big switch" that could/should be replaced by a wise usage of polymorphism.

In your example, it's `filler` that triggers the exceptions: if `filler.attr1` does not exist, then try the next attribute(s), and so on. The `filler` object has the knowledge, thus you should put the `fill_with` method in `filler`.

```
class FillerA():
    ...

    def fill(self, fillable):
        fillable.attr1 = self.attr1

class FillerB():
    ...

    def fill(self, fillable):
        fillable.attr2 = self.attr2
        fillable.attr3 = self.attr3

...
```

Now your function is just:

```
def fill_with(fillable, filler):
    filler.fill(fillable)
```

This function is closed for modification, but you can extend it by adding a new `filler` type (with the method `fill`). Bonus: `filler` does not need to expose his attributes anymore.